# Perl, make script timeout after x number of seconds?

Tags: perl, timeout

I have been searching on this but it is surprisingly hard to come by a straight answer to this (as php has a lot more info on this topic it seems).. I need to make my perl script die after a specified number of seconds because, as it is now, they are running too long and clogging up my system, how can I make it so the entire script just dies after a specified number of seconds?

I know about external solutions to kill the script but I would like to do it from within the perl script itself.

Thanks

Comment: Also see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238118/perl-alarm-working-intermittently

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[perldoc -f alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html):

```
[sinan@kas ~]$ cat t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Try::Tiny;

try {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
        alarm 5;
        main();
        alarm 0;
}
catch {
        die $_ unless $_ eq "alarm\n";
        print "timed out\n";
};

print "done\n";

sub main {
        sleep 20;
}
```

Output:

```
[sinan@kas ~]$ time perl t.pl
timed out
done

real    0m5.029s
user    0m0.027s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: thanks.. this helps me understand it better, I couldn't really wrap my head around the alarm function as the examples seem sparse in the documentation, I will try that

Comment: ONE question.. where would my actual script's code go? In the first "try" bracket? I think thats what has been confusing me on using alarm

Comment: @Rick: Put your code in the `main` function (or any other suitably named function). That way, you do not have too many levels of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

See `alarm` in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html):

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm $timeout;
    $nread = sysread SOCKET, $buffer, $size;
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}
else {
    # didn't
}
```

Comment: ok yeah I had been trying to use alarm for something else but I figured there would be a way to set a timeout for the entire script but I guess not.. I will look into alarm more.. thanks

Comment: It's best to avoid explicit use of `eval` and `$@`, as there are many subtle gotchas. Check out [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) for one of many alternatives (this one is the most lightweight) (and when I refresh the page I see that Sinan used it in his answer) :D

Comment: Rick, you can set a timeout for the entire script -- just call `alarm` outside of an `eval` block.

Comment: Rick, `alarm` generates a fatal exception.  If you don't catch it with `eval` it will terminate your script.